# Getting undefined on my Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting undefined in the console when trying to log the "data.billAmount" statement. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

I tried doing JSON.parse and JSON.stringify but those didn't work. I tried using dataType: 'json' but that didn't work. I'm not sure what else to try. I'm stuck.

PHP:

```
if (@$_POST['action'] == 'addBill')
{
    $billName = $_POST['bill_name'];
    $billAmount = intval($_POST['bill_amount']);
    $data = array(
        'billName' => $billName,
        'billAmount' => $billAmount,
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bills (billName, billAmount) VALUES(?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $billName);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $billAmount);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".addBill").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var billAmount = $('.billAmount').val();
    var billName = $('.billName').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {
            billAmount: billAmount,
            billName: billName,
            action: 'addBill'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.billAmount);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You missed dataType: 'json'

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help anything. Nothing logs to the console at all when I do that. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Can you show us the `data` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the 'data' @RayonDabre

Comment: Am talking about Ajax `response`

Comment: you sure about  url:'index.php' ?? you need to get data from the same page?? in this case you need to add exit(); in the end of your if statement .. and keep using dataType : 'json'

Comment: @RayonDabre When I do a general log of the data, it returns the JSON output, immediately followed by the HTML markup of the entire page.

Comment: If response if of type `json` and `billAmount` is immediate child of `data` then there is no way this can not work..

Comment: Ah, its fixed now! I had to use dataType: json along with exit() in the PHP script. Thank you so much @Mohamed-Yousef

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to move functionality which is responsible for adding bill into separate file. Then make AJAX call to that file and everything would works well, because if you want a particular value point request to particular file which `echo` that value for you...

No needs to looking for workaround when that could be done in clear and right way by separating functionality into smaller junks.
In case if you insist to use index.php 
after

```
$stmt->execute();
```

put one more line

```
exit();
```

As Mohamed-Yousef commented on question.

Comment: How would I split out the ajax call to a separate PHP file? I need to not only use Ajax to update the page, but I also need to update records in the database, and that code is inside index.php. So how would I hit both php files on the form submission?

Comment: That's complex question. See article ["Organize Your Next PHP Project the Right Way"](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/organize-your-next-php-project-the-right-way--net-5873) to get answers of how to organize project  stracture in the way which allow you to make such separation as described above.